# How to crop Image in expo react-native

Tags: image, react-native, image-processing, expo

I have using expo to build my photo editing app. I have used expo-image-manipulator (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/) to manipulate my image like rotation. But now I want Image cropping like cam-scanner or other photo editing apps which allows us to resize the height and width with aspect ratio. I have used **Surface** from **gl-react-expo** and **ImageFilters** from **react-native-gl-image-filters**. And want to use the filters after image cropped! So please suggest me Image crop npm packages which support the mentioned library.

Comment: Hey. Looking for the same thing. Did you mange to find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `expo-image-picker` and set allowsEditing to true. You can use this library to either take photos with `.launchCameraAsync` or choose images from from the phone's library with `.launchImageLibraryAsync` - both support `allowsEditing`.

link: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/

Comment: I have server render image, but how can I use expo-image-picker for server rendered images??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to do it, if you want to have more control over image cropping use `'expo-image-manipulator`' but if you are using `'expo-image-picker'` just activate `'ImagePickerOptions'` allowsEditing: true, here are the 2 documentations so you can guide yourself:

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/#actioncrop

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickeroptions