# I want to manually select the part of the photo I want and save accordingly in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to manually select the part of the photo I want and save accordingly. I want to crop it by moving it in this round area.

I'm using Expo image picker.

The screen shot here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d1oR.jpg

Can your help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how to enable cropping" check this issue : [How to crop Image in expo react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578429/how-to-crop-image-in-expo-react-native)

and the option "allowsEditing"

Comment: No, I'm not talking about that. I already do that, but it's not wanted that way. After adding the photo, it should be saved by swiping left, right, top or bottom in the part of the screenshot.

Comment: What do you mean ? Then this has nothing to do with your original question, right ? 

What you want to do is crop your image (you say you successfully managed to handle that), but then instead of saving by clicking on a button, you want to override and save by swiping ?